# Can I upload image to firebase storage from img tag

Tags: javascript, image, firebase, firebase-storage

Can I upload images from URL to Firebase Storage? 
Actually the scenario is that there is a img tag, and I want to upload that image to the firebase storge programmatically. 
If this can not be done, is there any option in firebase storage that we can upload it from external Link/Url?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase does not provide any tools to programmatically upload the contents of a URL to Cloud Storage.  What you will have to do is write some code to download the contents of the URL into memory, then use the [put()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference.html#put) method provided by the Firebase SDK to upload that data to Cloud Storage.